# How to SELECT the 2nd last 10 records in SQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*English is not my first language, sorry*

let's say that we have a table that contains 100 records how to execute a SQL query that selects the second last 10 records.

selecting from 90 to 80 will not work because the IDs are stored like this: 1,2,4,6,9,11... not like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reverse-order the table, then select the first 10 records offset by 10:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 10, 10;
```

This will return the rows in reverse order, however you could wrap it in another query to reorder the result by `Id ASC`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 10, 10
) AS Tbl ORDER BY Id ASC;
```